# systemd-networkd equivilent of "ip rule add..."

Tags: networking, systemd, iproute2

Basically the title says it all, what would be the equivalent to

```
ip rule add from 10.10.0.10/32 table 2
ip rule add to 10.10.0.10/32 table 2
```

in systemd-networkd?

I tried to setup something like

```
[Route]
Destination 10.10.0.10/32
Table=2
```

but this is not doing the trick and the manpages do not mention anything in this regards.

Answer (score 10):

If you have `systemd` 235 or higher, you can use the following:

```
[RoutingPolicyRule]
From=10.10.0.10/32
Table=2

[RoutingPolicyRule]
To=10.10.0.10/32
Table=2
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BRoutingPolicyRule%5D%20Section%20Options).

Comment: On Debian Stretch this only leads to an error: `Unknown section 'RoutingPolicyRule'. Ignoring.`

Comment: @Sprinterfreak Like I said this only works **if you have `systemd` 235 or higher**. [Debian Stretch is still at `systemd` 232](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/systemd).

Comment: `/32` (4) or `/128` (6) can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

As you may have already realized, there is currently no way to to this with systemd-networkd alone.

You can create a oneshot service unit like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure routes
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/sbin/ip rule add from 10.10.0.10/32 table 2
ExecStart=/sbin/ip rule add to 10.10.0.10/32 table 2
ExecStop=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```